# kendo UI bar chart- how to move the X axis

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

Here is the link for kendo UI bar chart: http://jsfiddle.net/nayanakalkur/ZPUr4/119/

In the fiddle example, X-axis is at '0'. How can i move the axis up or down the Y axis?
Suppose i want have the X-axis at 'y' value 10? How can this be done?

Code for the same:

HTML code:

```
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Site Visitors"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",

                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: series1,
                gap: 1.0,
                spacing: 0
            }, {
                name: "Unique visitors",
                data: series2,
                gap: 1.0
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Availability"
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true,
                    position: "bottom"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}"
            }
        });
    }

var series1=[56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 158000];
var series2= [-52000, 34000, 23000, -98000, 67000, 83000];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        createChart();

        $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"),
            firstSeries = chart.options.series;
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `valueAxis.min` to 10:

```
        valueAxis: {
            min: 10,
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "Availability"
            }
        },
```

Your JSFiddle modified in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZPUr4/120/

**EDIT:** If you want that the axis crosses at one specific value, then set `valueAxis.axisCrossingValue` to the value.

Example:

```
    valueAxis: {
        axisCrossingValue: -50000, 
        line: { visible: false },
        title: { text: "Availability" },
    },
```

And the JSFiddle modified http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZPUr4/126/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helped. But i want the bar in the negative Y axis to be plotted as well. How can i get this done? The Jsfiddle link - ( http://jsfiddle.net/nayanakalkur/ZPUr4/121/  ) has one negative value.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Can the X-axis color be changed to some other color?